# How to make condition, based on custom fields value?

Tags: custom-field, customization

So what i would like to do is order in some CSS depending on the value of a custom field.

The code below just says that if there is ANY value, do X, else do nothing...

```
<?php $pageNumbered=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page-number', true); ?>
    <?php if ( $pageNumbered ) : ?>
        <div class="page-number left">
            <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "page-number", true); ?>
        </div>              
        <?php else : ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

...what i want to do is say if the value is X do Y, if it is Z do XY etc etc...

Thanks guys!

Comment: So why not add in a couple of simple [if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) conditions?

Comment: Yeah, but what i am saying is that i don't know how to bind a specific value to the if condition

Comment: This is a PHP question, not a WordPress question. I vote we move it over to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but it's not clear what you want to do. From what I understand is you simply want to use an elseif statement:

```
<?php $pageNumbered=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page-number', true); ?>

<?php if ( $pageNumbered ) : ?>
    <div class="page-number left">
        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "page-number", true); ?>
    </div>              
<?php elseif($pageNumbered == "Z") : ?>
    <div class="page-number left">
        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "page-number", true); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you can edit you question to be clearer then I might be able to help more.

Comment: Sorry, i was unclear but i think you have just answered my question anyway! `== "Z"` means that the value must equal Z. Whereas `true` just needs to contain any value

Comment: @Infocentre you know there is an extensive list of syntax's and functions in the php manual :)

Comment: @infocentre - http://www.tizag.com/phpT/elseif.php quick tutorial on elseif PHP statements.